# How to extract date and hour in a specific timezone from epoch timestamp in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my Dataset I have a column of type **long** which denotes the time of an event.
I want to get the PST date and hour from this epoch as two more separate columns.

How do I go about it?

I wrote a UDF to get DateTime from epoch timestamp:

```
def getDateTimeFromTs(timezone: String): UserDefinedFunction = udf((timestamp: Long) => {
    val date = new Date(timestamp)
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone))
    format.format(date)
})
```

I can use the *hour* function in Spark to get the hour from the above dateTime Column. But how do I get the date now?

Comment: Can you post sample input & expected output ?

Answer (score -1):

Use Spark in built functions **`from_unixtime`** and **`to_utc_timestamp/from_utc_timestamp`** to get epoch time into `PST`.

- To extract **date** use either of these `date()`,`to_date()`,`date_format()`,`from_unix_timestamp()` functions.
- To extract **hour** use either of these `hour()`,`date_format()`,`from_unix_timestamp()` functions.

---

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("select from_unixtime('1588383884') as ts,
to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime('1588383884'),'PST') to_utc_from_pst,from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime('1588383884'),'PST') as from_utc_to_pst").
show()
//+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
//|                 ts|    to_utc_from_pst|    from_utc_to_pst|
//+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
//|2020-05-01 20:44:44|2020-05-02 03:44:44|2020-05-01 13:44:44|
//+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+

//extract date from timestamp    
spark.sql("select date(from_unixtime('1588383884')) as date").show()
spark.sql("select to_date(from_unixtime('1588383884')) as date").show()
spark.sql("select date_format((from_unixtime('1588383884')),'yyyy-MM-dd') as date").show()
//+----------+
//|      date|
//+----------+
//|2020-05-01|
//+----------+

//extract hour from timestamp
spark.sql("select date_format((from_unixtime('1588383884')),'HH') as hour").show()
spark.sql("select hour(from_unixtime('1588383884')) as hour").show()
spark.sql("select from_unixtime('1588383884','HH') as hour").show()
//+----+
//|hour|
//+----+
//|  20|
//+----+
```